# How to enable culture support in Kendo UI for Vue?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, culture, kendo-ui-vue

There are [Vue PWA template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa) and [Kendo UI for Vue](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui) used in my website. There is also Calendar component and need to set its culture to "ru-RU".

In simple jQuery app I would use code (from [Globalization Overview](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview)):

```
<script src="kendo.culture.ru-RU.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     //set current to the "ru-RU" culture script
     kendo.culture("ru-RU");
</script>
```

and this would perfectly work.

What is the common way to set culture in Vue App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find any official way in documentation. I used workaround (костыль) directly in my Vue component:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<kendo-calendar culture="ru-RU"> </kendo-calendar> 

// JavaScript
beforeCreate () {
  window.kendo.cultures['ru-RU'] = {
    name: 'ru-RU',
    numberFormat: {
      pattern: ['-n'],
      decimals: 2,
      ',': ' ',
      '.': ',',
      groupSize: [3],
      percent: {
        pattern: ["-n%','n%"],
        decimals: 2,
        ',': ' ',
        '.': ',',
        groupSize: [3],
        symbol: '%'
      },
      currency: {
        name: 'Russian Ruble',
        abbr: 'RUB',
        pattern: ["-n $','n $"],
        decimals: 2,
        ',': ' ',
        '.': ',',
        groupSize: [3],
        symbol: '₽'
      }
    },
    calendars: {
      standard: {
        days: {
          names: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
          namesAbbr: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
          namesShort: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб']
        },
        months: {
          names: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
          namesAbbr: ['янв', 'фев', 'мар', 'апр', 'май', 'июн', 'июл', 'авг', 'сен', 'окт', 'ноя', 'дек']
        },
        AM: [''],
        PM: [''],
        patterns: {
          d: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
          D: 'd MMMM yyyy "г."',
          F: 'd MMMM yyyy "г." H:mm:ss',
          g: 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm',
          G: 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss',
          m: 'd MMMM',
          M: 'd MMMM',
          s: 'yyyy"-"MM"-"dd"T"HH":"mm":"ss',
          t: 'H:mm',
          T: 'H:mm:ss',
          u: 'yyyy"-"MM"-"dd HH":"mm":"ss"Z"',
          y: 'MMMM yyyy',
          Y: 'MMMM yyyy'
        },
        '/': '.',
        ':': ':',
        firstDay: 1
      }
    }
  }

  window.kendo.culture('ru-RU')
}
```